# Weird Class Not Found Exception in

Tags: jdeveloper, classnotfoundexception

I would like to know why I'm getting this exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlForm
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:297)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:305)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:246)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:179)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlForm
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:297)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:305)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:246)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:179)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

If I have already add "ADF Faces Runtime 11" and "ADF Faces Components 11" to my project ?... Thankx in advance... I am using JDeveloper 11g ! :D

Answer (score 0):

I've heard that BC4J runtime and ADF web runtime may be needed.  ADF has a lot of strange dependencies and it isn't the easiest to also know what libraries are available on your weblogic server without fiddling.  Try adding libraries one by one in the "deployment/library dependencies" settings.